# Webpack está gerando os arquivos manifest.js em uma pasta diferente

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Estou utilizando o webpack como Vue. Na hora de dar npm run build, o arquivo manifest.js é criado com o caminho /static/, enquanto os outros arquivos são criados com o caminho static/.

Assim se eu coloco a aplicação num subfolder, por exemplo, 127.0.0.1/webapp
vai apontar que o arquivo não existe por que vai procurar no caminho raiz.

Onde na configuração do webpack eu ajeito esta configuração?

Estou usando o vue-cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O arquivo index.js no caminho "config/index.js" estava assim

```
  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
```

e mudei pra isso

```
  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
```

Funcionou.